# Powershell install service PermissionDenied, CouldNotNewService

Tags: powershell, installation, windows-services

I created a windows service (let say, named `foo`) by using C# Windows service template (.Net 4.5.1 framework using VS2013).

After I completed the project, I wanted to install it to my PC using `Powershell`. The script I used to install the service is from this [page](https://www.devtxt.com/blog/install-a-windows-service-using-powershell). (with courtesy and credit to: Mr. Phil Campbell):

```
$serviceName = "foo"
$exePath = "C:\Program Files\foo\foo.exe"
$username = "someUser"
$password = convertto-securestring -String "somePassword" -AsPlainText -Force  
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password

$existingService = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='$serviceName'"

if ($existingService) 
{
  "'$serviceName' exists already. Stopping."
  Stop-Service $serviceName
  "Waiting 3 seconds to allow existing service to stop."
  Start-Sleep -s 3

  $existingService.Delete()
  "Waiting 5 seconds to allow service to be uninstalled."
  Start-Sleep -s 5  
}

"Installing the service."
New-Service -BinaryPathName $exePath -Name $serviceName -Credential $cred -DisplayName $serviceName -StartupType Automatic 
"Installed the service."
$ShouldStartService = Read-Host "Would you like the '$serviceName ' service started? Y or N"
if($ShouldStartService -eq "Y")
{
    "Starting the service."
    Start-Service $serviceName
}
"Completed."
```

However, I got the following error:

> CategoryInfo : PermissionDenied: (foo:String) [New-Service],
>   ServiceCommandException +  FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   CouldNotNewService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewServiceCommand

In this line:

> At line:22 char:1
>   + New-Service -BinaryPathName $exePath -Name $serviceName -Credential $...

Why is that so? How do we fix this?

Note: My user `someUser` has admin right (or to be more precise, my user is *the* admin) and I `Run Powershell as Administrator` too.

Comment: Hmm. What happens if you remove `-Credential $cred` from the `New-Service` line?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler hey, you are right! That is the culprit which causes the issue! Thanks! But why is it so?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why it doesn't like your credentials; One possible guess - does your username have to be in the form `"COMPUTER\User"` ?